# Where can I read about how NTFS saves and deletes files?

Tags: save, ntfs, recover, delete-file

I have a homework assignment to do in which I need state possible ways we can recover deleted files from a computer using NTFS. The assignment asks me to think of any pieces of information that may be vital for forensics. However, I don't know how NTFS saves, deletes, and overwrites files in the first place!

Here is something similar we learned in class:

In class we learned that FAT32 saves files in clusters of blocks. When we save a file, it uses up sectors in a cluster, but the file may not use all of the sectors in a cluster, or even all the space in a block.

When a file is "deleted," the file name in the directory has it's first letter changed to a sigma, and then the location of the stored file is considered unallocated (aka may be overwritten). So we can still search for this file (using certain techniques) and recover it! Even if a new file is written in that address, the new file may be smaller than the previous file. In such a case, the remnants of the previous file that was stored there remains because they were not overwritten. We can recover this as well, assuming its not fragmented.

Well, that's what we learned in class. I have to write up a similar piece for the NTFS, but I can't find a simple site that specifically explains how files are saved and deleted in NTFS in the first place. Can anyone give me a link with some valuable reading material?

EDIT: I've found the perfect site that explains exactly what I need. I will post it here for future readers:
http://wiki.sleuthkit.org/index.php?title=NTFS_File_Recovery

Comment: Off topic. This is not a programming question.

Comment: you can also find about NTFS at http://www.ntfs.com/

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best place to start is with Microsoft Technet. Check out the following article on [how NTFS works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781134%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

The things you most likely want to dig further into are the master file table, journaling, and possibly some topics on deleted data recovery.

You may learn a good amount my looking at document for forensics tools such as [sleuthkit](http://www.sleuthkit.org/).

You may also want to check out the [NIST Publication SP 800-86: Guide to Integrating Forensic Techniques into Incident Response](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-86/SP800-86.pdf).

Lastly, something which is pretty cool about "hiding" data in NTFS is alternative data streams. Alternative Data streams are typically not visible to Windows operating systems, but still take up disk space. They come from the Mac world. [IronGeek's Guide](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds) is a good place to start understanding ADS.

Comment: Thanks! here's how i learned it works:
When a file is deleted, I don't know what happens to the entry in the MFT. The $Bitmap still shows where that entry's data is located, however, it simply says the location is unallocated (aka available for writing). Then when a new file is written and has its data saved in that same location, the remnants of the older file that occupied that space may still be found if the new file is smaller.

So where can i read about what happens to the entry in the MFT of a deleted file? What happens to that entry when the file is overwritten? Thats all thats left!